# Named Entity Recognition (regex for places)

Tags: python, regex

How would you go about a regex that detects places of the following formats:

```
Word+, Word+, Word+
```

In a nutshell I want the regex to match a city name followed by a comma, followed by a state name followed by a comma, followed by the country name followed by a comma. Where the city name, state name and country name can contain multiple words separated by spaces or just one word.

---

Here's my failed attempt at it:

```
r'([A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+?, ([A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+?, ([A-Z][a-z]+ ?)+?'
```

It can detect places like:

- Hyderabad, Andhra Pradesh, India

But not places like:

- Bangalore, Karnataka, India
- New York City, New York, United States

Comment: I can't understand your example. How did i  differentiate between the matched and unmatched ones?

Comment: [I can't reproduce this behaviour. It all matches.](http://regex101.com/r/rI9eK2/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to obtain the city, country, state in separate capturing groups, you can use:

```
r'(?i)([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*), ([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*), ([a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*)'
```

Otherwise, this one match the substring format:

```
r'(?i)[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*(?:, [a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*){2}'
```

If you need to have a capital letter at the start of each words (but keep in mind that all the city names don't have capital letter at the begining of each word, and that each word can be separated with a dash, example: *Boulogne-sur-Mer*, *Rouperroux-le-Coquet* or *Jouy-en-Josas*), you can adapt the two patterns replacing `[a-z]+` with `[A-Z][a-z]*` and removing the modifier `(?i)`

A more realistic pattern can be:

```
r'([A-Z][a-z]*(?:[ '-][A-Za-z]+)*), ([A-Z][a-z]*(?:[ '-][A-Za-z]+)*), ([A-Z][a-z]*(?:[ '-][A-Za-z]+)*)
```

That can be improve (for example, this doesn't handle accentued letters).

Comment: Just a minute, I'm testing

Comment: How do I mention that the names must start with a capital letter?

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: Not in your orginal post, but this can easily be done.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I just need to match <city>, <state>, <country> in a nutshell

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: First at all note that many city names don't have a capital letter at the begining of each word. But if you want to do that: remove `(?i)` and replace each `[a-z]+` with `[A-Z][a-z]*`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Worked like butter! +1 and accepted!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte can you please update your answer to reflect your last comment?

Comment: +1 for solution that handles spaces and initial caps